# VBA write a column to a text file formatted by another column

Tags: vba, excel

I have two columns of data.

```
file,category
a,1
b,1
c,1
d,2
e,2
f,2
g,3
h,3
i,3
```

I want to print the first column to a text file which is formatted by the second column.

eg.

```
category 1
a
b
c
category 2
d
e
f
category 3
g
h
i
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you rearange your data in a `Pivot Table`?

Comment: the main goal of my script is to produce 2 files that are inputs to some other software I can already produce one of the files, its just a portion of the other file that I need which is above. Also it is a requirement that the excel file remain unchanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with your posted data:

```
Sub testlist3()
    Open "C:\TestFolder\testlist" & Format(Now(), "_yyyy-mm-dd_hh-mm") & ".lst" For Output As #1
    Dim N As Long, L As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Print #1, "catagory " & Cells(1, "B").Value
    Print #1, Cells(1, "A").Value
    For L = 2 To N
        If Cells(L, "B").Value <> Cells(L - 1, "B").Value Then
            Print #1, "catagory " & Cells(L, "B").Value
        End If
        Print #1, Cells(L, "A").Value
    Next L
    Close #1
    MsgBox "done"
End Sub
```

Comment: it produces the "category 1" line for each row in the file

Comment: I have assumed that the "a,b,c,d..." values are in column **A** and the "1,2,3..." values are in column **B** .